# Launch my app in background using voice commands from Cortana

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone, cortana

I modified my Windows Phone 8.1 application (universal app with just the Windows Phone project live yet) to have a  VoiceCommandDefinition (VCD) file in place and this works fine to start my app in foreground mode and handle parameters.

But I want to let my app quickly answer some app specific questions like it is described in [this blog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/input-and-devices/launch-a-background-app-with-voice-commands-in-cortana) for Windows 10. I have tried to apply this blog but the app manifest modification fails. It does not know the:

> uap:AppService

When I looked it up, it seems to be available for Windows 10 only. So I searched up the internet mainly MSDN and stack overflow, but I could only find examples that run the app in foreground.

Does anyone know an example how to provide answers to the Cortana content page with a background service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only App service can meet your requirements.

But App service is new in Windows 10, so you cannot use uap:appservice in Windows Phone 8.1 application. You can see [App to app communication](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2015/3-765) video from 26th minutes which introduce the app service.

So you can use universe windows app to develop. Sample is [Cortana voice command sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CortanaVoiceCommand) as you see in that blog.

Comment: That was I was afraid of. That I can only start my app to then respond with voice and have to wait for Windows 10 Mobile.